# Populating Template with data from another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, excel-formula, populate

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now. It might be good to know I'm not very familiar with Excel formulas & VBA and that I'm using Excel 2010.

I have two separate sheets, let's call them "Data" and "Template".

In "Data" I have ~10 000 cells with information (running adjacent from E2 to E10001, sorted numerically).

In "Template" I have templates which I want to populate with the data from "Data". The problematic thing here is that the "Template" sheet is filled with ~10 000 empty recurring templates, where one template covers 18 columns and 6 rows. All templates are adjacent to each other and running vertically.The second template starts the row after the first template ends, so if the first template stops at row 6, the second template starts at row 7.

How do I automatically pick a value from E2 in "Data" and place it in D1 in "Template" for the first template and then then pick the value from E3 in "Data" and place it in D7 in "Template", all the way to the last template?

I've been trying by using formulas that adjust automatically when adding a new template:

```
=OFFSET('Data'!E7!;-5;0)
```

But the problem being that the row offset has to be dynamic. By the third template, as an example, the -5 needs to be -10 for the formula to return the right cell reference (at the fourth template -16 and so on).

I hope I've explained my problem in a non-confusing way.

Comment: Please show more of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly I think this does what you need:

```
=INDEX(Data!$E$1:$E$10001,ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/6+1,0),1)
```